# I am having difficulty getting an accurate output from my maclaurin series for sin x

Tags: java, math, trigonometry

```
     // a java program that displays the maclaurinseries math function
     // sin x = x - x^3/3! + x^5/5! - x^7/7!
     // sin x = (-1)^n * x^(2n+1) / (2n+1)!

    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class maclaurinseries
    {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        double x;
        double counter=1;
        double factorial =1;
        double result=0;

        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("enter a number");
        x=input.nextDouble();

        while(x>=counter) {

            factorial=2*factorial*counter+1;
            result=result+(Math.pow(-1,counter)) * (Math.pow(x,2*counter+1))/(factorial);
            counter++;

        }

        System.out.println("Maclaurin series is" +result);

    }

    }
```

Here is the output of my code when I entered the number 3.14 for x:

> enter a number
>   3.14
>   Maclaurin series is-24.935440878754584

As you can see, my output should be 0 , not -24.935330878754583 when I    substitute in x=3.14 into the function sin x. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you comparing `x` to `counter` ?

Answer (score 3):

First, you don't want the number of iterations controlled by the value you've entered.  You'll want a reasonable number of iterations to be reasonably accurate.

```
while (counter <= 10) {
```

Second, your factorial calculation is messed up.  You want (2n + 1)! each loop, and you still want the first loop to have 1!.  Change the calculation to include a factor of 2n and a factor of (2n + 1), and move the factorial calculation after the `result` addition, to set it up for the next loop.  You'll also want the first term to be positive, so use `counter + 1` as the exponent in the sign determination.

```
    result = result + (Math.pow(-1, counter + 1)) *
        (Math.pow(x, 2 * counter - 1)) / (factorial);
    factorial = factorial * (2 * counter) * (2 * counter + 1);
    counter++;
}
```

(Edit: Changed `Math.pow(x, 2 * counter + 1)` to `Math.pow(x, 2 * counter - 1)`, because `counter` already starts at `1`.)

Sample output:

```
enter a number
3.14
Maclaurin series is 0.001592652393160744
```

More:

```
enter a number
3.14159
Maclaurin series is 2.6530608840492444E-6
```

More:

```
enter a number
1.57079
Maclaurin series is 0.9999999999799855
```